# React Native & Formik pass custom params to onSubmit

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, formik

I'm using `Formik` to submit my forms.
I'm trying to add a custom params to my onSubmit function, so that I can get `values` of the form and that custom parameter.

```
const handleSubmit = async (customParam) => {
    console.log(customParam);
    console.log('Values : ');
    console.log(values);
}


<AppForm initialValues={{ rejectionComment: "" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit(myCustomParam)}> //My FORMIK form
    <AppFormField multiline={true} numberOfLines={4} name="rejectionComment" secured={false} autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect={false}/>
    <SubmitButton title="Valider" /> //Validation button
</AppForm>
```

With this code, i'm able log the `myCustomParam` but I cannot get the values of the form `[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: values is not defined]`

If I change `onSubmit` to `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` and `handleSubmit` to `const handleSubmit = async (values) => {console.log(values);}` i can log my values, but cannot add my custom param.

Can you please provide some help ?

Comment: Where is `values` defined? Also, you're executing your handleSubmit function when you pass it to your AppForm. Wrap it as a callback, i.e. `() => handleSubmit(myCustomParam)`

Comment: Oh that's probably why I had the function triggered on render. `values` is directly defined by onSubmit : `onSubmit: (values: Values, formikBag: FormikBag) => void | Promise<any>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two changes.

1. Change your `handleSubmit` function to accept two arguments (it also doesn't need to be async, unless you're doing more things than you have shown here).

```js
const handleSubmit = (values, customParam) => {
  console.log({ values, customParam });
};
```

2. Pass `values` where Formik provides them.

```js
<AppForm
  onSubmit={values => { handleSubmit(values, myCustomParam); })}
  ...
>
```

Explanation:

When you change your code to `onSubmit={handleSubmit)`, the Formik component calls it with the form values.  The long form of this would be `onSubmit={values => handleSubmit(values)}`.  Since your custom param is defined outside of Formik, you need to pass it in to the function manually.

Answer (score 1):

Abe pointed the obvious. By using the callback, i've been able to define both values and custom params :

`onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values, "test")}`

```
const handleSubmit = async (values, customParam) => {
    console.log(values);
    console.log(customParam);
}
```